# How to find all the colors in a photo with Ruby

Tags: ruby, image-processing, colors

Does anyone know of a Ruby library that can list all of the colors in a photo, as well as listing them in order of frequency?  Or is it possible that RMagick already can do something like this?

If no one knows of one, how exactly could I get started on making such a tool?  I have a great idea for a program I'd love to try, however I just don't know much about image processing as I've never done it.

I'd be very grateful for any tips or info to point me in the right direction!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[color_histogram](http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#color_histogram)